# Accessing Large Files In C

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I need to access a file larger than 2gb using C. During one run of the program a variable number of bytes will be read from the file and the location of the next position saved. During the next run of the program the file position is read and a number of bytes are read starting from that location.

The complication is that occasionally the file may be 'compressed' by copying it to a new file, less any bytes that have already been read (I think copying is the only way to do that). The number of bytes removed in this way will also be saved.

I need to know the current position of the file from the original start for synchronizing with another file. This should be easy because it is just (current_offset + deleted_bytes).

The reason it is not easy is the fseek only uses long int indexes which limits the file to 2gb, and fsetpos uses an fpos_t structure for the position index, which is not a number and can't be converted back and forth to one. I don't know of any way to use a long long int index for file positioning, which would be the ideal solution.

What do I do?

Comment: Which platform?  `ftello()` and `fseeko()` might be an option.

Comment: ftello and fseeko will be POSIX.1 compliant, but the >2GB is a filesystem dependent issue too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On windows you can use [`_lseeki64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yee101t(v=vs.80).aspx) to do 64 bit seeks.

For compatibility with linux, you can also add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` at compile time, and then do this in one of your headers:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__ // or whatever you use to find out you're compiling on windows
#define lseek _lseeki64
#endif
```

then use `lseek()` everywhere as usual. This works because windows ignores the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` flag, and linux won't see the redefinition of `lseek`.

There's also [`_fseeki64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/75yw9bf3(v=VS.80).aspx) if you prefer a `FILE*` version, and there are equivalent 64 bit `tell()` and `ftell()` functions too (`_telli64()` and `_ftelli64()`).

Comment: You're welcome. Another note on making it portable - I can't remember whether windows declares `off_t`, so you might also need `#define off_t __int64` on windows (so you can write code to [the `lseek()` interface](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lseek.2.html)). But I'm not 100% sure - maybe `off_t` is defined somewhere now.

Comment: @TimothyJones How do you set _file_offset_bits in Windows? I am compiling from Visual studio 2008 on a 32bit Windows7 machine. I tried to follow this example http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2006-12/msg03560.html but I get the following error c2371: 'off_t' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: There isn't an equivalent - `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is ignored on windows. You'll need to use the 64 bit versions of the functions you want. I believe `off_t`  [is a long integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k.aspx) (ie, [only 32 bits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367072(v=vs.85).aspx)) on windows. Your error is appearing because that code tries to re-typedef `off_t`. You can work around this with the suggestion in my comment above- `#define off_t __int64` (but only on windows, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Add the compilation flag `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, which makes `fopen`, `fseek`, `off_t` etc. become 64-bit and usable for manipulation of files greater than 2 GB in size. See [Large File Support in Linux](http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html) for more information.

Comment: Excellent solution. Unfortunately I should have mentioned I am using Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: I guess I didn't think of a compiler specific solution. I searched the Visual Studio documentation and found SetFilePointer that uses 64bit indexes in Windows. I was hoping to make my code more portable than that though. Maybe I need to learn how to use #ifdef to detect what platform it's on and have a whole list of compiler directives or something.

Comment: I'll leave the answer in case it's useful to Linux/OS X users. A Makefile will allow you to determine compilation options by platform.