# checking a file from a certain offset without reading the entire file

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, byte

what I want to do is open a file(which is huge) and read from a certain point of bytes to an offset.

in c# this can be done with:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(file).Skip(50).Take(10).ToArray();
```

the problem with this is that it reads the entire file but since my files can be huges this also takes a long time. is there a way to read parts of a file similiar to this method but WITHOUT reading the entire file? In c preferably

Comment: See `seek` or `fseek` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the [`fseek()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) standard library function to move ("seek") to the desired position:

```
FILE *in = fopen("myfancyfile.dat", "rb");
if(fseek(in, 50, SEEK_SET) == 0)
{
  char buf[10];
  if(fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, in) == 1)
  {
    /* got the data, process it here */
  }
}
fclose(in);
```

Comment: Worth noting that if your file is very big (> 2GB), and you're using a 32 bit Windows application, this approach won't work if you need to seek past the 2GB mark, because a 32 bit long int won't be able to hold the desired offset. You'll need a different approach, as mentioned in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003405/32-bit-windows-and-the-2gb-file-size-limit-c-with-fseek-and-ftell

Comment: thx for the quick reply my files can be more than 200gb big. my program will only run on linux so this probably isnt a problem?

Comment: It will be a problem for 32 bit Linux too. This answer might also help you. It's pretty much exactly what you need, and covers Windows and Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8875668/2609288 More details on large file handling from C under 32 bit Linux are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/seeking-and-reading-large-files-in-a-linux-c-application/1035713#1035713